# how to change class name on keydown, using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[how can i toggle the class on a specific keydown for ex keydown == 84 ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFpj0.png) 
**GIF** : **https://gyazo.com/a6658c29e2317d7d7163e7d2804b6c9b**

i tried something like this but im very far away from getting it to work , on the gif above im clicking the toggle-btn

```
    $(function () {
  $("#enemyCellSkin").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 84) {
      send();
      return false;    
    };

    if (e.keyCode == 84) {
      $("#enemyCellSkin").removeClass('toggle-btn.active').addClass('toggle-btn');
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: If the key code matches 84, the first `if` statement returns from the handler function so the second `if` won't run at all.

Comment: i dont know that much about javascript/jquery, what i wanna do is to toggle the setting while in the game by pressing a key, so i dont have to click the menu, open the settings tab, and turn it off by clicking ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this you can press keycode 84 and the toggleClass method will do its work

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which ==  84){
        $('#target').toggleClass('red');
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    
    <div id="target">test</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about class only , this is the js path ```document.querySelector("#enemyCellSkin > div.toggle-btn.active")```

Comment: nevermind , i accesed it with ```document.querySelector('#enemyCellSkin > div:nth-child(2)')```